# Relation between residue and closeness of solution for non-linear system $Ax=b$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, finite-element-method

Let $A(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix depending on $x$, $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that,
$$A(x)x=b,$$
i.e. we have a system of non linear equations. Let $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be its solution and $u_h\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be its approximate solution. Define $R(x)$ as the residue of the above system, i.e., $R(x)=A(x)x-b$.

Say $\|R(x)\|_{l^2}\leq \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is some tolerance (say clsoe to $10^{-7}$) and $\|.\|_{l^2}$ is the $l^2$ norm.. Then can we say $\|u-u_h\|_{\infty}\leq 1$? Do we have any closeness between approximate and analytical solution?

Comment: The difference between the analytical and the numerical _solution_ is given by : $S(x)=x-A^{-1}(x)b$ . So $\,R(x)=A(x)S(x)$ . Then you can write something like $\,\|R(x)\|_{l^2}=\|A(x)\|_{l^2}\|R(x)\|_{l^2}\leq \|A(x)\|_{l^2}\,\epsilon\,$ and the only problem is to find an numerical value for $\,\|A(x)\|_{l^2}$ . At least that's what my rusty knowledge says :-(